# Cannot instantiate the type TreeNode

Tags: java, swing, collections

```
package com.cnu.ds.tree;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Tree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.t = 1;
        treeNode.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.t = 2;
        treeNode.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.t = 3;
        treeNode.left.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.left.t = 4;
        treeNode.left.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.right.t = 5;
        treeNode.right.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.left.t = 6;
        treeNode.right.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.right.t = 7;
        // //////////////////////
        treeNode.left.left.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.left.left.t = 8;
        treeNode.left.left.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.left.right.t = 9;

        treeNode.left.right.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.right.left.t = 10;

        treeNode.left.right.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.left.right.right.t = 11;

        treeNode.right.left.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.left.left.t = 12;
        treeNode.right.left.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.left.right.t = 13;

        treeNode.right.right.left = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.right.left.t = 14;

        treeNode.right.right.right = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.right.right.right.t = 15;

        levelOrder(treeNode);
        levelOrderReverse(treeNode);
    }

    public static void levelOrderReverse(TreeNode root) {
        Queue<TreeNode> treeNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        TreeNode newRoot = root;
        treeNodes.add(root);
        treeNodes.add(null);
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean flip = false;
        while (!treeNodes.isEmpty()) {
            root = treeNodes.remove();
            if (root == null) {
                if (flip) {
                    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                        root = queue.remove();
                        int r = stack.pop();
                        int l = stack.pop();
                        root.left.t = r;
                        root.right.t = l;
                    }
                }
                flip = !flip;
                if (treeNodes.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println();
                treeNodes.add(null);
            } else {
                if (root.left != null) {
                    treeNodes.add(root.left);
                }
                if (null != root.right) {
                    treeNodes.add(root.right);
                }
                if (flip) {
                    stack.push(root.t);
                } else {
                    queue.add(root);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        levelOrder(newRoot);
    }

    public static void levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        Queue<TreeNode> treeNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        treeNodes.add(root);
        treeNodes.add(null);
        Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        while (!treeNodes.isEmpty()) {
            root = treeNodes.remove();
            if (root == null) {
                if (treeNodes.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println();
                treeNodes.add(null);
            } else {
                if (root.left != null) {
                    treeNodes.add(root.left);
                }
                if (null != root.right) {
                    treeNodes.add(root.right);
                }
                queue.add(root);
                System.out.print(root.t + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

1 
3 2 
4 5 6 7 
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8

the above is part of code snippet for the below problem suggested in the site.
Reverse the alternate level nodes of the binary tree. 
a 
/ \ 
b c 
/ \ / \ 
d e f g 
/ \ / \ / \ / \ 
h i j k l m n o

Modified tree: 
a 
/ \ 
c b 
/ \ / \ 
d e f g 
/ \ / \ / \ / \ 
o n m l k j i h

initially i got error as "TreeNode cannot be resolved as a type"
Then i imported java.swing after that am getting error as "Cannot instantiate the type TreeNode"

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate a `TreeNode` with `new` because `TreeNode` is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html). You can however say:

```
TreeNode node = new SomeClass();
```

where `SomeClass` is a class that implements the `TreeNode` interface.

Comment: This code snippet is taken from the below link [Click Here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5068704572243968) they have published output even. Got confused

Answer (score 0):

TreeNode is an interface and interface can never be instantiated using the new operator or keyword. You can use the TreeNode as the object reference or handle but you will have to use some implementing class with new keyword for instance creation. Visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) to know more about TreeNode and its implementing classes.

Comment: i understand its a interface,but how the above program successfully returns the mentioned output?/Am i missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't instantiate an `interface`.`TreeNode` is an interface which can only be implemented or referenced to any class implementing `TreeNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Try org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode like this:

```
TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode("SomeID", null);
```